# RuntimeException when using Flink's MapFunction with Cassandra "Insert" but not with "Statement"

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, query-builder, apache-flink

While experimenting with Flink streaming together with Cassandra I ran into an interesting problem when trying to generate INSERT statements in a MapFunction. If I used a `DataStream<Insert>` I would get a confusing `RuntimeException` thrown at me. However, by using `DataStream<Statement>` instead, everything worked as I expected it to, even though I still use an `Insert` instance in the code that executes.

I found a solution (using `DataStream<Statement>`) by trial and error, but am still confused about what is causing this. Is it intentional or a bug? I have been unable to find any explanations by googling, so might as well ask here if anyone knows what is going on.

Expected output (using `DataStream<Statement>`):

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka://flink/user/jobmanager_1#-638132790]
01/17/2017 15:57:42 Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
01/17/2017 15:57:42 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
01/17/2017 15:57:42 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
01/17/2017 15:57:42 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
INSERT INTO tablename (name,age) VALUES ('Test Nameson',27);
01/17/2017 15:57:42 Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to FINISHED 
01/17/2017 15:57:42 Job execution switched to status FINISHED.
```

Error output (using `DataStream<Insert>`):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: The field private java.util.List com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.BuiltStatement.values is already contained in the hierarchy of the class com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.BuiltStatement.Please use unique field names through your classes hierarchy
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getAllDeclaredFields(TypeExtractor.java:1762)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.analyzePojo(TypeExtractor.java:1683)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:1580)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:1479)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoWithTypeHierarchy(TypeExtractor.java:737)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateCreateTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:565)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getUnaryOperatorReturnType(TypeExtractor.java:366)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getUnaryOperatorReturnType(TypeExtractor.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.getMapReturnTypes(TypeExtractor.java:120)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream.map(DataStream.java:506)
    at se.hiq.bjornper.testenv.cassandra.SOCassandraQueryTest.main(SOCassandraQueryTest.java:51)
```

Code example (switch the commented code for the two different cases):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.RichSourceFunction;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Statement;
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Insert;
import com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.QueryBuilder;

public class SOCassandraQueryTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);

        DataStream<Map<String, Object>> myDataStream = env.addSource(new RichSourceFunction<Map<String, Object>>() {

            @Override
            public void run(SourceContext<Map<String, Object>> ctx) throws Exception {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map.put("name", "Test Nameson");
                map.put("age", 27);
                ctx.collect(map);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancel() {
            }
        });

        /* Works just fine */
        DataStream<Statement> debugDatastream = myDataStream.map(new MapFunction<Map<String, Object>, Statement>() {

            @Override
            public Statement map(Map<String, Object> datarow) throws Exception {
                Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("tablename");

                for (Entry<String, Object> e : datarow.entrySet()) {
                    insert.value(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                }
                return insert;
            }
        });

        /* Throws RuntimeException if using "Insert" instead of "Statement" */
//        DataStream<Insert> debugDatastream = myDataStream.map(new MapFunction<Map<String, Object>, Insert>() {
//
//            @Override
//            public Insert map(Map<String, Object> datarow) throws Exception {
//                Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("tablename");
//
//                for (Entry<String, Object> e : datarow.entrySet()) {
//                    insert.value(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
//                }
//                return insert;
//            }
//        });

        debugDatastream.print();

        env.execute("CassandraQueryTest");
    }
}
```

Environment:

- Java 8
- Flink 1.1.3 (Cassabdra driver from this maven package)
- Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flink is analyzing the types you are sending over the wire to generate fast serializers, and to allow access to your keys when building windows or when shuffling data over the network.

The problem here is probably the following:
- When using `Insert` as the user type, Flink tries to generate a `PojoSerializer` for the type, but fails with that `RuntimeException`. I think the behavior is not correct. I've filed a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-5549) in the Flink project for the issue.
- For the `Statement`, Flink sees that it can not serialize the type as a POJO, so its falling back to a generic serializer (in Flink's case Kryo).

I think this documentation page is the closest we have that describes how Flink's serialization stack works: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/types_serialization.html

Comment: I have opened a PR for this bug: https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/3154